# Android. Как можно получить значение времени, которое устройство показывает пользователю в углу справа в баре?

Tags: android, время

Как можно получить значение времени в формате unixtime, которое устройство показывает пользователю в углу справа в баре?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```